# Background-image as a direct child of <body> and with proportional scaling - possible ? But hight % does not work

Tags: css, layout, background-image

[Here is my project](http://postimg.org/image/wxay2eniz/) (1000px x 1230px). I want  [this](http://postimg.org/image/nzs3x6y09/) element taken from my project (this header picture originally has 1500px x 354px) to:

**1.** be inserted with background-image property 
**2.** that background-image to be direct child of *body tag* and 
**3.** so that height and width would scale proportionally along with scaling the browser window.

If it was possible to carry out the above operation the paramerers would be width:100% hight:19.19% but when I enter hight:19.19% the image does not show at all, QUESTION: WHY IS THAT SO? I inserted background-image into *section* tag and this is how it seems to somehow work (but I do not know why it works):

```
section.super { 
    position:relative;
    padding-top:11.8%;
    padding-bottom:11.8%;
    background: url(header.jpg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    margin: 3% auto 0; 
}
```

If I insert a div or article inside the given section tag above and specify width and height with % for background-image inside this div or article, the height WOULD WORK. But as a direct child of body tag the height does not work, why is that?

I know that there is an alternative IMG TAG but it will not work in rensponsive layouts where in different page sizes I will want substitute different .jpg (for instance) files (with higher and lower size) in which case I would need to paste different images to the same element in mobile styles, in tablet styles and deskop styles.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure i completely understand your problem, have you tried to use:

```
background-size:cover;
```

instead of:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

?

Comment: But if I implement the following code the hight of the header will not change with window resizing: section.super { 
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:19.19%;
 background: url(header.jpg);
 background-size:cover;
 margin: 3% auto 0;

}

Comment: with the above code when I resize my browser I get the following result http://postimg.org/image/l8upkgl8h/ and it should be more like this http://postimg.org/image/gw73tvmth/ Just compare those two pictures

Comment: Then the problem you have does not have to do with the image but with the div that contains the image :)

Just put a max-height:200px; in the css of the div that contains the image. That way, the div containing the header will not grow bigger than 200px no matter what the height of your browser window is :)

Answer (score 0):

on your file css you should put:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://s12.postimg.org/ymlx2m65n/header.jpg");
}
```